# Storing three objects in one "list" in Java

Tags: java, list, object, storage

I need to store two sets of information about an object in a kind of table.

But all the tables I looked at store multiple 2ndary (<1, 2, 3>) values per primary value.

Is there a precoded class for this or will I have to make my own?

Comment: You could put a `List` within `List`, you store `Properties` in a `List`, you could store a POJO in a `List`, you can store arrays in a `List`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is using two Maps for each object.

e.g. for object of class A you want to store a corresponding B and C object. So you could create a HashMap of B and a HashMap of C with A (or some unique property of A) as a key. Therefore, given A you can lookup either B or C.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert ArrayLists of 3 items within an ArrayList.